# Reverse for 'bid' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dasboard/orders/add/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to set the the status of a model object to "Off" based on passed id, How do I achieve this.

Here is my views.py

```
def bid(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        bid = Order.objects.get(id=id)
        bid.status = "Off"  # change field
        bid.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard')
```

urls.py

```
  path('dashboard/orders/add/<int:id>', bid, name='bid')
```

html

```
   <a href="{% url 'order_detail' order.id %}" style="text-decoration: none; color:white;"
                      class="orders_made">
```

Comment: It is having trouble with the a `{% url 'bid' %}` where you did not specify a value for `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove :

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Your request is not a POST method is GET

And i think this line should be like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'bid' order.id %}" style="text-decoration: none; color:white;"
                      class="orders_made">
```

Comment: What I want is there is a list of orders, so once a user clicks on one order, it opens another view on details about that particular order. Then on the detailview, there's a button to acept the order so once the button is clicked it should update the status of that particular order to Off